# Using loc on already loc'd dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im working with a huge database right now (700 mil rows+) and to analyze it correctly some code was written:

```
SQL_Query = pd.read_sql_query(query,connection)
current_frame = pd.DataFrame(SQL_Query,columns = ['foo','bar','zoo',...])
unique_slice = pd.unique(current_frame['zoo'])
for current_slice in unique_slice:
 dataframe_slice = current_frame.loc[current_frame['zoo'] == current_slice]
 unique_bar_slice = pd.unique(dataframe_slice['bar'])
 for current_bar_slice in unique_bar_slice:
  current_bar_dataframe = dataframe_slice.loc[dataframe_slice['bar'] == current_bar_slice]
  unique_foo_slice = pd.unique(current_bar_dataframe['foo'])
  for foo_slice in unique_foo_slice:
   #Do stuff
```

Question:
Is it similar to:

```
SQL_Query = pd.read_sql_query(query,connection)
current_frame = pd.DataFrame(SQL_Query,columns = ['foo','bar','zoo',...])
unique_slice = pd.unique(current_frame['zoo'])
for current_slice in unique_slice:
 dataframe_slice = current_frame.loc[current_frame['zoo'] == current_slice]
 unique_bar_slice = pd.unique(dataframe_slice['bar'])
 for current_bar_slice in unique_bar_slice:
  current_bar_dataframe = current_frame.loc[(current_frame['zoo']==current_slice)&(current_frame['bar'] == current_bar_slice)]
  unique_foo_slice = pd.unique(current_bar_dataframe['foo'])
  for foo_slice in unique_foo_slice:
   #Do stuff
```

And what is the most efficient way to work with pandas when I need subframe lvl3 of main frame based on values in columns?
Thanks!

Comment: could you please tell difference between both quires(both are looking same)

Comment: Thank you for the question!
On the first query I'm loc'ing dataframe, that is the result of loc' of main frame. Second query is working with main frame only and adding more conditions on loc' operator.

Comment: I made a test, it's completely same, first variant works much more faster. Thank you!